# revert back to the default terminal z shell

Tags: macos

I accidentally changed my default macOS z shell to bash shell.  How could I change back to the default macOS shell.

I wrongly entered

```
cd ~

/bin/bash
```

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: I wrongly copied the whole block and pasted it directly into the terminal window.

Comment: If that is all then you have not changed your shell - either open a new shell in Terminal.app or just hit ^d in the bash shell

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It works!  And the following also works:  https://support.apple.com/zh-tw/guide/terminal/trml113/mac

Answer (score 5):

Running `/bin/bash` within zsh isn't different from running `nano`, it starts the new binary "on top" of the running zsh. So to get "back" to zsh you just need to quit the newly started bash shell by typing `exit`.